# How to get blob data from azure container in chunks through an API call?

Tags: node.js, azure, rest, get, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to retrieve data from azure blob container through an API call, it is working fine but for files with 20 or 30 MB its takes almost 3-4 minutes to get response from API which is not good from user perspective,Is there a way to get data from azure in chunks so that we can show a progressive data to the user ?  Below is node js code snippet I am using to get data :

```
var request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });
const fileUrl = "File Url";
request.get(fileUrl, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const image = body.toString('base64');
        res.status(200).json({ image })
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({})
    }
});
```

Comment: So you are looking for a demo about showing a progress bar while downloading?

Comment: No , I want to display the chunked data which I will get from azure, so that user will have the idea that the data is not loaded completely yet, like the data showing in below URL , initially it shows blur data and then it displays the data in complete resolution, and you will find that it is getting data in chunks, when you go through the network of the site.
https://f.giorlando.org/2018/07/web-viewers-for-fmri/

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written so far.

Comment: Added Code please check

Answer (score 0):

Request the [Content-Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-properties) of your Blob:

> The size of the blob in bytes. For a page blob, this header returns the value of the x-ms-blob-content-length header that is stored with the blob.

[Get the blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) by using [Range Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/specifying-the-range-header-for-blob-service-operations):

> Range Optional. Return only the bytes of the blob in the specified range.

> The second format, bytes=startByte-endByte, is available for requests using all versions (2009-04-14 through the newest version), and for all versions of the storage emulator service. This range will return bytes from the offset startByte through endByte. For example, to specify a range encompassing the first 512 bytes of a blob, you would pass in either of the following headers:

> Range: bytes=0-511